# Ignore the first row in a list python

Tags: python, arrays, list, raspberry-pi

I have the following data stored as col?

```
Location
47.608941, -122.340145
55,66
33,22
55,22
```

How can I ignore the first row and print out the rest in Python?

```
for index in range(len(col)):
    print col[index]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just start at index 1:

```
for index in range(1, len(col)):
    print col[index]
```

but that is not that idiomatic. Slicing and looping directly over the list is more so:

```
for column in col[1:]:
    print column
```

If the list is large, you can create the implicit loop iterator explicitly:

```
it = iter(col)
next(it, None)  # skip first entry
for column in it:
    print column
```

or use [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to skip items:

```
from itertools import islice

for column in islice(col, 1, None):
    print column
```

Comment: Yes the list is very large, >100, so which method would you recommend. Btw, it is running on a Raspberry PI with a processor that is not powerful and I want to conserve power as this PI will be battery powered.

Comment: More than a 100 is not very large, really, but not creating a new list (allocating more memory) is probably something you still want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
for item in col[1:]:
    print item
```